# Display all subterms of a custom taxonomy filtered by parent terms

Tags: customization, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy which i called 'fonte' that should display a list of books. These are divided in two parent terms, 'mixed' or 'single'. So the hierarchy is something like that:

Mixed

- book1
- book2
- book3 ...

Single

- book4
- book5
- book6

I'd like the page template to show the two parent terms 'mixed' and 'single' as selectable filters, so that when I click on one of them they display their child terms, but I believe I'm not able to do this.

What I have so far:

```php
              <?php
          $terms = get_terms( 'fonte' );

          ;

          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          if ($term->parent != 0){
          // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
          $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

          // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
          if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
              continue;
          }

          // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
          echo '  <div class="element">


              <div class="pf-body c27-content-wrapper"><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>        </div>
                    </div>';
          echo  $term->description; // This will return the description of the term

          }
}
          ;
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Javascript/jQuery to initially hide the child entries and then display them only when the parent term is clicked? This behavior could be set up as a toggle to allow child entries to become hidden when the parent is clicked.